# How Odoo create a field (which methods are invoked)

Tags: python, odoo-10

I am trying to get the knowledge about how odoo creates a field, which methods are invoked while creating it. I am following below link.

[Understand-Odoo-Model-Part2](http://www.mindissoftware.com/Understand-Odoo-Model-Part2/)

I have tried to change **_add_field** , **setup_base** and **setup_attr** methods present in "**odoo/models.py**","**odoo/fields.py**" initially by printing a simple statement, but it generates an error. **"IndentationError: unexpected indent**" 
Once I got success printing a statement but it was printed when I started odoo server (while initializing all the existing fields).

So my question is still at the point from where I started,When we create a new field in Odoo 10 in a model what actually happens in the back end. How different methods are invoked as I have to perform some custom operations on Odoo fields latter on using this concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python IndentationError: unexpected indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634700/python-indentationerror-unexpected-indent)

Comment: Kindly read the question completely. The main question is how different methods are invoked when we create a new field in Odoo 10 in a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we press the **create button** it renders the respective form view in any case(either for creation of field or model or anything), no function is invoked at that time. After the data is entered when we press **save** button, it calls the function against save(I don't know exactly at the moment which function is it). The function in save decides if it was an **edit call** or **create call**

Specific to your case i.e. creating new field, it will call **create** function in **odoo/odoo/models.py** which is responsible for creating new record.